# I am trying to debug my flutter app in my android mobile but I am getting this error in VS Code

Tags: android, flutter, debugging

> Launching lib\main.dart on Infinix X655C in debug mode...
> lib\main.dart:1
> Checking the license for package Android SDK Build-Tools 29.0.2 in C:\Users\Josh\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\licenses
> Warning: License for package Android SDK Build-Tools 29.0.2 not accepted.
> Checking the license for package Android SDK Platform 30 in C:\Users\Josh\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\licenses
> Warning: License for package Android SDK Platform 30 not accepted.
> Build failed with an exception.
> I am also attaching the full screenshot of the error.

Any help would be appreciated. [image: Here is the image of the error]

Comment: run flutter doctor and show the terminal window I think you dont accept android licences

Comment: Seems like you didn't complete the installation of your Android SDK properly. Run a flutter doctor to see what's wrong. I reckon a reinstallation of the SDK might fix it.

Comment: Yes @RavindraS.Patil, you were right. I had not accepted android licenses. After running flutter doctor and accepting the license, the error was gone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes @RavindraS.Patil, you were right. I had not accepted android licenses. After running flutter doctor and accepting the license, the error was gone.